# Update Library name and add library to menu using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have here 2 questions :

1. I created a document library with a specific name using the HTTP request action and would like to give this document library a friendlier name. If i use the same HTTP Request action, it creates an additional library with the new name> Any idea how i can simply update an existing library name ?
2. Does anyone know how to add a newly created library automatically into the left handed menu of the site ? When i create it with the HTTP Request, it goes into the site content but does not show up in the site menu...

Thanks a lot for your help ! (sorry but my "hello all" is not showing up..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete answer to your 2 questions asked above

1. You want to createt a SP Library using an HTTP request right? if so you can easily do that using Power Automate and "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action like this :
   [image]
2. For showing your SP Library to Navigation, you need to add :"OnQuickLaunch": true to your JSON body as follow :

[image]

here is the JSON code :

```
{
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.List"
    },
"BaseTemplate": 101,
"Description": "",
"Title": "LIB23",
"ListExperienceOptions":1,
"OnQuickLaunch": true
  }
```

3. Now you want to update your existing library "Title" to a new Title, you need to do some changes on your HTTP request as follow :

[image]

as you can see :

- The first change i made, i add ../getbytitle("old library title") in order to access the endpoint of that specified library,
- second, you need to add "***X-HTTP-Method : MERGE***" and "***IF-MATCH : ****" headers
- and then update your JSON code with your new required title, easy heh ?

### Please, let me know if this worked for you, it's working for me pretty fine !

Comment: Hi @Aimen Boulahia, thanks for your answer. Yes this works. I cold create a new library, i just added "OnQuickLaunch: true" and now i see it in the menu. but what i was mentionning is that i still can't update the library name. so my screenshot was showing this is how to create the library (and add it to the menu) but how can i update the title ? if i follow what Jerry_MSFT said, it's the same as creation, that, just creates an additional library... thanks !!

Comment: So your need now, how to update the Title of an existing Library, right ?

Comment: Ok so i quickly tested... but i hqve qn error becquse of the GetByTitle("libraryName") it says that "web/lists/GetByTitle("MyLib") is not valid.  but it that's the right library name....

Comment: AAAAAHHHH !! ok... it works, i just put single quotes in the parenthesis of GetByTitle.  Cool !!! thanks a lot for your help !!! :-)

Comment: Yeah, indeed single quotes works all the time, while double quotes work on French tenant, happy for you

Answer (score 1):

For updating the library title, please use the body below:
It is an update request.

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.List"
  },
  "Title": "NewLibraryName"
}
```

For creating libraries showed in left navigation, you will need to add the property

```
"OnQuickLaunch": true
```

My test works like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answer.

For the title update, it's the same thing as creating a new library. when i try this, it creates a new one with the new name... my URI is the same , method POST and body identical.

am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Here, you want to create a new library with a specified name, or you want to update the title of an existing library ?

Comment: I want to update the name. I have a short name which is "LibraryName" and i have a "FriendlyName" property. I create the library, it takes the LibraryName...but then i want to update it so it takes the "FriendlyName".  is it clearer ?   So I guess i have to add a HTTP Request and add to the URI " _api/web/list/getByName("LibraryName")   so in the body I can have Title reference "FriendlyName" . I just didn't have time to test if this is correct yet, i have lots of calls and meetings today :-P

Comment: Very well, check my answer again, i just update it